# What is the equivalent of System.setProperty() (Java) in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, system

I'm trying to set os name and os arch with my app (C++);
in java I've previously worked with System.setProperty(), what I exactly need to do is:

```
System.setProperty("os.name", "Windows 7");
System.setProperty("os.arch", "x86");
```

PS: I am trying to run an external exe file with Windows 7 compatibility mode; because I am using an exe which is only compatible with Windows 7, so I want to make it compatible with newer Windows versions (8, 10)

Comment: when translating from one language to another it is better to explain what the code does. There is no equivalent of this in c++, but if you tell us why you want to do that, there might be a solution

Comment: Those are variables in the Java environment; "setting them" in C++ is not something you do. This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so you might want to add what you're trying to accomplish by this.

Comment: "x86" might be something you tell the compiler when *compiling* the C++ code, not while running it.

Comment: to find the 'equivalent' we need to understand the purpose of those 2 lines. What do they actually do, why would you put those 2 lines in a given program?

Comment: The direct equivalent would be to declare a global variable containing a map of strings to strings. But global state is generally a bad idea, and there's probably a better way of achieving what you actually need.

Comment: What do you mean by "Windows 7 compatibility"?

Comment: i have an exe wich is only compatible with Windows 7 i'am trying to run it with Compatibility Mode to make executing it possible in newer Windows version

Comment: You can't set an EXE's Compatibility Mode when executing the EXE in code. However, when a user sets the Compatibility Mode in the EXE's properties, the settings are stored in the Registry, which you can update before executing the EXE. See [Running an Application as Administrator or in Compatibility Mode](https://www.verboon.info/2011/03/running-an-application-as-administrator-or-in-compatibility-mode/) for details. However, if the EXE is properly manifested, Windows will already know the EXE only supports Windows 7 because the manifest can state as much, so you shouldn't have to do anything.

Comment: On many PC platforms, there are already *environment variables*, which contain the Operating System and architecture information.  If your program needs this information, get it from the environment variables.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: You generally do not plan to *get* information, when you call functions that start with *set*.

Comment: Thanks every one , you were generously so helpful.